# If function is executed then... Extend a function

Tags: jquery

I'm working with sharepoint and I want to calculate something when a function executes
ex:

```
if (SP.UI.addStatus().executed()){
    ....
}
```

Is this possible without modify the "originally" code, but instead "extend" the function?

Comment: Please provide more spec info.

Comment: Are you looking to include a callback to the `addStatus()` method so you can run code when it completes?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the decorator pattern to add your behavior to the the existing function:

http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#decoratorpatternjavascript